# Camunda Task not showing up in Process Definition Tab using Tomcat

Tags: camunda

I followed this camunda tutorial on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxtZf5VD6lQ) and created a simple, small, first project. I managed to generate a war file.

In the tutorial they are using the enterprise version and I'm using the community version. My camunda is running on a tomcat server instead of a wildfly like in the tutorial.

I found out that I've to put my `.war` file into the `webapps` folder.
After copying it I refreshed the `processes` tab in the Camunda Cockpit and I saw that it created a folder with the same name as my war file but the Process Definition is not listed. I still only see the default Invoice Receipt Process...

Any help on why my process definition is not showing up in the list is appreciated. I'm completely new to camunda and as there is no error message or so I've no idea about where to start looking.

Comment: After investingating further I realized there were indeed some error messages which I didn't see at first because the log was quite cluttered... Due to those I could find out the bug and fix it...

Answer (score 0):

If there's no error message, you've probably either:

- Placed your process definition in the wrong location (it needs to be in the project's `src/main/resources` directory) or
- Neglected to mark your process model/process definition as executable. (To mark it as executable, make sure you've checked that box on the "General" tab for the process definition itself.)

It's possible that you may have also mistakenly set something up incorrectly in your project. I'd recommend using one of the "Get Started" tutorials to ensure you have everything setup properly. This one is probably the best one for your situation: https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/spring/project-setup/.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked both of your options and both of them are already satisfied. I guess I'll just check out that project and try to modify it to my needs.

Comment: @oemel09 I think that's the right approach. As with most applications like this, the format of your instruction set - in this case of the WAR file itself - needs to be correct in order for everything to work as desired. Going through that tutorial will provide you with a very useful archetype for future work. Good luck!